# Formal solutions of semiring equations

Tags: species, co.combinatorics, ra.rings-and-algebras

I am looking for a general theorem which would tell me when a formal series solution exists for an equation over a semiring.  One may assume that the semiring is equipped with a (formal) derivative.  One may further restrict to the case 
$$A(X) = H(X, A(X))$$
where $A$ is a formal series in $X$ and $H(X,Y)$ is a *polynomial*.

Motivation: Trying to find a more precise set of conditions for which Joyal's **implicit species theorem** holds.  [For example, one can easily lift the condition $H(0,0)=0$ to $H(0,0)$ is constant].